# How to responsive for 3 item using col-sm-6 in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a price table include 3 columns.

My code like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using `col-xx-4` is work perfect. Only at `col-sm-4`, my page is broken. Like:

[image]

I decide using `col-sm-6`, it shows like:

[image]

Look good. But **at the final item**, it should be at **center screen** and **`margin-top: 15px`** to look pretty.

I don't know how to do it. Have any method to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use offset

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be working at `col-sm` instead of both `col-lg` and `col-md`.

Comment: @makshh it's working in Ipad (768px). But on my PC (1366px - 1920px). It broken like this image. http://i.imgur.com/bbQ6urt.png. I think `col-sm-offset-3` only apply for `.col-sm-`, but seem this apply for both `.col-md-` and `.col-lg-`. I don't want this.

Comment: You are right, it's similar to `col-sm-6` for example, it will apply to `md` and `lg` also. In order to reset offset on bigger screens you have to use `col-md-offset-0` in addition to your div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Bootstrap's columns is that you can't make the columns equal in height. I recommend you use `flex` for this.